# Should richsnippets in JSON-LD format contains info that doesn't exist on a page?

Tags: seo, schema.org, json-ld

Should richsnippets in JSON-LD format contain info that actually is not listed on the page?

For example, I have an article that actually is displaying only the content and the author name.
But in the JSON-LD richsnippet I've added additional publisher info like url, logo, email, telephone, etc.

Is the above example a good practice or should be avoided and add only those props that actually exists on page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s fine from the viewpoints of Schema.org and JSON-LD. More data is better. And anyway, there’s not always a webpage, or a webpage with visible content, to begin with.

Specific consumers of your data ([like Google](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/policies)) might not like it, though (but discussing their guidelines/preferences is off-topic on Stack Overflow).

Comment: Ok, but is fine the same from the viewpoints of Schema.org in a combination of json-ld and RFDa? Have I to add all hidden content as a <meta prop="..."/> ?

Comment: @user3845133: The syntaxes Microdata and RDFa allow to use `meta` and `link` elements in the `body` exactly for cases where you want to provide content that is not visible on the page.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question.